# Using Unity.Mvc3 with HierarchicalLifetimeManager and Unit Of Work pattern no longer Lazy Loading

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, dependency-injection, entity-framework-4.1, unity-container

First, my UoW inherits from DbContext.

I moved over to using Unity.Mvc3 and added this line to my registrations:

```
Container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
```

Once i moved to this, my lazy loading for Entity Framework has seemed to stop working. Here is an example:

```
public class Process
{
     public Guid Id {get;set;}
     public virtual Guid? StatusId {get;set;} //this is the FK EF uses.
     public virtual Status Status {get;set;}
}

public class Status
{
     public Guid ID {get;set;}
     public Name {get;set;}
}

//DTOs
public class ProcessDto
{
     public Guid Id {get;set;}
     public Guid? StatusId {get;set;} //this is the FK EF uses.
     public StatusDto Status {get;set;}
}

public class StatusDto
{
     public Guid ID {get;set;}
     public Name {get;set;}
}
```

The Satuses are loaded in the context before we call the Cre

```
//Process Service
    public ProcessDto Create(ProcessDto dto)
    {
       var processEntity = new Process(){StatusId = dto.StatusId}
       processRepository.Add(processEntity)
       unitOfWork.Commit()
       //at this point, before using Unity.Mvc3 the Status would be proxied into the   processEntity. Moving to Unity.Mvc3 it is like Lazy Loading stopped working.
       return Mapper.Map<Process,ProcessDto>(processEntity);
    }
```

Stepping through the code the request is not terminated until after the Create call. Not sure if anyone has run into something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Status` property is not virtual so the entity could never be proxied for lazy loading and Unity or any other IoC container has no effect on this.

Also you are using `Process` constructor directly - if you create instance of Process it cannot be proxied and lazy loading cannot work. You must use `Create` factory method on `DbSet<Process>` to get proxied entity.

Comment: I failed to put the virtual on this example, but I can assure you that they are actually set in my model. I'll update my example. Regarding your comment on the Process constructor, like I said, above, the Status is actually coming in when I go back to using the Microsoft Unity resolver and remove the Unity.MVC3 version.

Comment: What type (the real runtime type) is your `processEntity` when it works?

Comment: it is a Process entity type. same as above. Everything you see there is the same as my setup. The only difference is the use Unity.MVC3 resolver. It is like the UoW is getting dumped at some point.

Comment: Ok. I see the why it works now. I missed this: *The Satuses are loaded in the context before we call the Create* So there was no lazy loading all the time because data were loaded.

Comment: they are part of the Context before I call create, yes.So, after my commit in the Create method, the FKs for Statuses get picked up by EF to load them onto the Process entity. Only if I am using the "out-of-the-box" Unity resolver, however. It's really strange.